# Is it possible to add a hint onto an encrypted Microsoft Excel document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, encryption

I have an encrypted Excel document and I don't want to forget the password. Is it possible to put a hint on the password, to help me remember it. I'm looking for something like the Windows log-in screen hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't *think* Excel has any feature like that... all of the data in the document is supposed to be locked/encrypted until the correct password is entered.

For a "hint" that's visible to everyone all the time, I think your best bet would be to integrate your "passowrd hint" into the **filename** of the document, since the filename's always visible.

Maybe naming the file something like "**Spreadsheet - favourite food**".